# Modal content not working

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, jscript

I've started using Modals however I've bumped into a slight issue- I'm trying to put several of them up but something in my code is linking all of them together, thus not allowing me to put different content in each so whatever is in the first's content ends up being in all of the others overriding whatever I've written in the other bodies. Thank you to anyone who can help me figure out what in my code is doing that!

```
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
</button>
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">MIDDLE TIER</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="bs-example">
               <table class="table">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>RUN JOB</th>
                           <th>ACTION</th>
                           <th>TARGET</th>
                           <th>MODEL</th>
                           <th>REPORT KEY</th>
                           <th>REPORT NAME</th>

                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <td>GL LOAD</td>
                           <td>PROFILE/IMPORT</td>
                           <td>CR Staging (For All Funds)</td>
                           <td>Not Indicated- To Be Developed</td>
                           <th>N/A</th>
                           <th>N/A</th>
                       </tr>

                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you be more specific about your problem... here is my issue with modal, maybe it help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257927/jasny-bootstrap-rowlink-close-modal-is-not-closing

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar recently. I added the below js code to destroy modals when closed and it works well:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Hard to tell whether your issue is the same from the code supplied, but it's worth a try.